# AudioClip trouble

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am getting an Expected Identifier error when trying to compile an applet with AudioClip.
I plan on adding this to a JFrame, and I was hoping to get the AudioClip to loop.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Audio extends Applet
{
AudioClip sound = getAudioClip(getCodeBase(), "myssy.au");
sound.loop();
}//end of Audio Applet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a more efficient way of playing a sound in a JFrame

Use a `Clip` - see the example on the [Java Sound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).  It uses a `JOptionPane` rather than a `JFrame` (to prevent the daemon thread of the `Clip` from stopping at the end of `main()`), but the principle is the same.

Comment: No worries, but I thought it contained valuable information that was pertinent to the 'Expected Identifier error'.  It was only the last part that made me pause, as I was about to up-vote it.  (I suppose it is '6 of one, half dozen of the other' with a query of this nature from a new user - the answer may end far from where the question started!)